# Is there a pattern to map a range of numbers to a string?

Tags: java, design-patterns, object-oriented-design

I need a function that will take the name of a town and return a specific range of numbers that is assigned to that town. I won't be using a database. The simplest way to do this is

```
    //Pseudocode
    public arr getTownNumbers(string town) {

      switch (town)
        case: "Pasadena"
          arr["min"] = 183
          arr["max"] = 194
          return arr
        case: "Charlotte"
          arr["min"] = 268
          arr["max"] = 270
          return arr
    }
```

This seems dirty though. Is there a pattern for storing this kind of data?

Comment: Huh? It does seem dirty, though I don't know what the underlying problem is. Nor do I understand why one would write code like that in the first place (trying to solve the 'how to do this' with a underlying bad design doesn't really help anyone).  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @MichaelT I'm not sure what you mean. You said yourself that it would be bad design to do it this way, so you're pointing out the problem yourself?

Comment: If you're storing a largish amount of structured data like this in your code base, you're by definition using a data base. It might not be a fancy relational, SQL-using, index-administrating RDBMS (although using one might be a good idea), but it's a data base. Even storing these data in an external data file would be better than embedding them into code logic like this.

Comment: Looks like a job for a `dictionary` or `key value pair` collection

Comment: In Java, switch 'smells'.  Switch on a string literal, while valid makes me raise red flags. Having an array(?) to store data also makes me go "what are you doing there that wants an *array*?"  There is probably some other class that can be designed that actually answers the questions that you have of the data, but I don't know enough about the problem to be able to say "this is how you do it."

Comment: @MichaelT Thanks. I know it's a smell, which is why I don't want to do it that way and I'm here asking if there's a better way. I had to put them in an array since it returns a range of numbers but you can't return more than one value. The problem is pretty basic. I just need to store which range of numbers goes to which town.

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: @gnat In what way did I not do that? I put the best solution I could come up with right there in the question. Since the best I can come up with is still bad and I'm aware of that, I'm asking for a better way. The answer may be obvious to you, but this is new to me. There is probably some terminology for what you're supposed to do in this situation, but I don't know it, so I don't know the correct search terms that you would think are obvious.

Comment: I for one would at least try entering "java map a range of numbers to a string" into web search and checking top results

Comment: @gnat Okay, so you're saying that when I ask a question, I should include a list of all the google searches that I could think of which didn't answer my question? I could do that, but it doesn't seem to be the normal way of asking questions on this site.

Comment: regarding what's normal here, consider taking a look at [meta guidance](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important) referred in one of prior comments

Comment: Could this possibly be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/218240)? Why do you need these min and max values for cities?  Do the actual values matter?

Comment: @DanPichelman yes, it likely is an XY problem. Given a little bit of time to think more about the text of the post, I will endeavor to realign the question to the problem that I answered (that appears to be the right one) and remove the XY nature of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of things that 'smell' about this code. It just feels awkward and forced. Having a 'switch' statement is one of those 'something is likely wrong around here' things that people point at unless it is clear that this is the *right* thing... and the String switch in Java just rubs me wrong every time I see someone try to put it into use.

You've got data. Putting data in code is a 'bad' thing. Data should be in some data format. Be it a database or a property file or some other storage system.

Lets do a property file for an example.

```
city.Pasadena.min=183
city.Pasadema.max=194
city.Charlotte.min=268
city.Charlotte.max=270
```

You then read it with the [Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html) class.  Other approaches for reading from an actual database exist.

And there, now your data is separate from the code.

You could then have a nice little object that looks something like:

```java
class Range {
  private int min;
  private int max;

  public boolean in(int value) {
    return value <= max && value >= min;
  }
}
```

And you could extend this with making iterators or disjoint ranges or a `Set<Integer> butNotIn`.